# Finding a single row in MONGO DB driver java using _id field

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to get a single record using the _id field , here is my code

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id","52a6a2cc05e1c80fd5e9295c");

DBCursor cursor = blogTable.find(query);
while (cursor.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println("got u");
    dataText.setText((cursor.next().get("content:encoded")).toString());
}
```

I simple don't get any data and I am quite sure the id exist
.please help

Comment: What happens when you print out just "cursor.next()"? Not sure if that will potentially show you the data or not. Are you getting "got u" to print?

Comment: Actually i got it I need to pass the object as it is and not convert it to string by using toString method

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that the String you are calling out as "52a6a2cc05e1c80fd5e9295c" is actually an ObjectID in the MongoDB.  If this is the case, your lookup is...

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("_id", new ObjectId("52a6a2cc05e1c80fd5e9295c"));
DBObject dbo = blogTable.findOne(query);
if ( dbo != null ) {
    System.out.println( "got u " + dbo );
} else {
    System.out.println( "not found" );
}
```

You need to know the types of things in MongoDB.